# How the View Resolvers work in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I need to know how any of the ViewResolvers supported in Spring actually map to the physical path .

For example lets say I am using InternalViewResolver where I set in config as :

```
internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/BOOT-INF/classes/templates/");
internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
```

If this is how I set it and I build and package it as a jar file then where exactly the Dispatcher servlet is going to find the view. Please feel free to ask any question.

Comment: If you are using jar package as a deployment, then what is the problem if you have `webapps` folder?

Comment: the files in the webapps folder is not picked up at the time of building it. I suppose since I have given jar as a way for packaging in pom.xml its not picking it up. I have given it as war also and kept in the location webapps/WEB-INF/templates folder then it works fine with prefix as /WEB-INF/templates . But I need to know why this path is working and what path I should give if I am having jar as a way of packaging.

Comment: If you want to keep views inside package then you should use your own defined viewResolver ( reading views from class path resources ) I believe.

Answer (score 0):

So as the name suggest, using prefix and suffix, you can create full path to the view.

Let say you have **prefix** as "/BOOT-INF/classes/templates/" and **suffix** as ".html", and you are returning new ModelAndView("**helloworld**") from controller, then final path becomes

`path = prefix + view name + suffix`

`path = "/BOOT-INF/classes/templates/" + "helloworld" + ".html"`

`path = /BOOT-INF/classes/templates/helloword.html`

So spring dispatcher servlet will search for the full file path under the **webapps** folder of spring application.

Comment: I don't have a webapps folder and I am placing html file in the resources folder. Then how the spring is going to find it. Since in the end the package is getting deployed as jar so contents of webapps folder is not going to be in deployment.